# Cancel file modification in unit test

Tags: php, file, unit-testing, phpunit

I begin to use PHPUnit (with DBUnit extension) and i'm facing a problem.

The code i want to test is editing some files located server side, and i want to know if it's possible to 'rollback' this modification at the end of the test, as the rollback on database does.

I think I can save the files before the test, launch test, then replace the edited files but maybe there is a better solution with PHPUnit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're testing file modifications, then you should really be using a virtual file system such as [vfsStream](https://github.com/mikey179/vfsStream) - that way, you can simulate file access in a sandbox environment